# How can I multiply pairs of rows of a column conditional on the difference between the rows of another column without using nested loops?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a dataframe.

```
      x_coord   y_coord   u 
 1      12      16       100   
 2      17      16       105         
 3      22      12       95     
 4      27      12       98
```

I want to calculate the product of pairs of rows under u under multiple conditions based on the other columns which I've done with nested loops:

```
prod_pairs<- NULL
prod_pairs<- matrix(nrow=4, ncol=1)

for (i in 1:4) {
  for (j in 1:4) {
    if(i!=j & data$y_coord[i]==data$y_coord[j] & data$x_coord[i]-data$x_coord[j]==-5) {
      prod_pairs[i]<- data$u[i]*data$u[j]
      break
    }
  }
}
```

My actual dataset is much larger and I am repeating this multiple times with other columns in place of u and other value in the 3rd condition under the if statement (it's -5 here; so I will repeat with +5, -10, +10 etc).

The nested loops are quite slow and I've been trying to vectorize this but to no avail. Is there a way I can speed it up?

Also, I want to try to create a function so I can input other columns and values in the 3rd condition of the if statement. I was trying to combine vectorization with a function that can do this but could not make it work.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach might be to join the table on itself, requiring that the join be equal on y_coord, and be offset by (-5, 5, 10, etc) on the xcoord. This function does that, and also allows you to pass a different u column (default is `"u"`, and a different offset or xdiff (default is `-5`)

```
get_paired_products<- function(df, ucol="u", xdiff = -5) {
  result = df[df[,x2:= x_coord - xdiff], on=.(y_coord, x_coord=x2), nomatch=0]
  result[, prod:=get(ucol)*get(paste0("i.",ucol))][, .(row_a = row, row_b=i.row, prod)]
}
```

If input is:

```
df = data.table(
  x_coord = c(12,17,22,27),
  y_coord = c(16,16,12,12),
  u=c(100,105, 95, 98),
  row = c(1,2,3,4)
  )
```

Then output is:

```
> get_paired_products(df)
   row_a row_b  prod
1:     2     1 10500
2:     4     3  9310
```